# Attempting to set up an IPSec LAN to LAN VPN, do my subnets overlap?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I've been trying to troubleshoot why my IPSec VPN isn't working properly, and am getting very slow responses from TP-Link. I've read that the connection will not work if the subnets overlap, knowing almost nothing I've come here to ask if they do.  Router A LAN is 192.168.6.0/24 and router B is 192.168.4.0/24. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.6.0/24 and 192.168.4.0/24 don't overlap.

When an address is written in the form of X.X.X.X, each X is 8 bits.

/24 means the first 24 bits starting from the left must be unique per network.

So for addresses in the form of X.X.X.X, the first three X's must be different, if your netmask is /24.

This is the case for your question.  You have two networks with unique addresses, one with IP ranges 192.168.6.1-254, broadcast 192.168.6.255 and a second with 192.168.4.1-254, broadcast 192.168.4.255.

Comment: Thank you! So X.X.X.X/32 would be an exact address, or would that be totally redundant?

Comment: /32 doesn't make sense if you are talking about routing because any network has to have a broadcast address, and there's no room for a broadcast address if all 32 bits are used to identify the network. /31 is as low as you can go, 192.168.0.2/31 means for example 192.168.0.2 is your only valid IP for host assignment/use and 192.168.0.3 is the broadcast address.

Comment: @LawrenceC: That's all wrong. "Broadcast addresses" and "network addresses" are completely irrelevant for routing, and are only meaningful for on-link subnets. (And for that matter, they're irrelevant for point-to-point connections.) So it's competely normal to have /32 routes or /31 routes, and even /32 addresses on an interface as long as they don't need to define a subnet. (Speaking of /31 subnets, it is an exception and has _two_ valid host addresses and no broadcast address. Previously it had no valid addresses as a subnet at all -- though, of course, was still valid as a route.)